# trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Tags: php

I have this PHP function for converts all the html special characters to html entities, UTF-8 compatible.

```
function safe($input) {

 $text = trim($input); //<-- LINE 31

 $text = preg_replace("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/", "\n", $text); // cross-platform newlines
 $text = preg_replace("/\n\n\n\n+/", "\n", $text); // take care of duplicates 

 $text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
 $text = stripslashes($text);

 $text = str_replace ( "\n", " ", $text );
 $text = str_replace ( "\t", " ", $text );

 return $text;

}
```

Now, I check my script using acunetix web vuln scanner and i see this error :

```
This page contains an error/warning message that may disclose sensitive information.The message can also contain the location of the file that produced the unhandled exception.

This may be a false positive if the error message is found in documentation pages.
This vulnerability affects /cms/submit.php. 
Discovered by: Scripting (Error_Message.script). 
Attack details
URL encoded POST input access was set to 2
Error message found: 

<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\includes\safefunc.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: What's the value of `$input`?

Comment: What does `var_dump($input);` output? `trim()` expects a string, but as the Warning says, you're passing an array instead.

Comment: Update My Question please see this.

Comment: That is still the same error.. can you show the input to your `safe` function.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the error is self explanatory and this function is not built to handle arrays.  If you need to handle arrays then something like this:

```
function safe($input) {
    if(is_array($input)) {
        return array_map('safe', $input);
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the Warning, and your answer is there.

Trim must receive a string as parameter, not a array.
Use

`var_dump($input)` to check your input variable type.

Could you show the code that call function *safe()*?

Answer (score 1):

try to stringify the $input by using

`json_encode($input)`

it worked for me